# IE Radio Button Alignment Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, radio-button

I have an ASP.Net-MVC application that is mostly complete. However, I have one page that contains radio buttons. When that page is displayed in Firefox or Chrome, the radio buttons are displayed in a horizontal row (which is what I want). But when the page loads in IE, the radio buttons show up in a column. I am using the Html.RadioButton helper.

I have tried editing several of the css properties in the master stylesheet, but I have not been able to come up with a solution.

Have any of you encountered this before? If so, what could the solution be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting the radio buttons in a table row. It's not the most elegant solution, but it works all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It would be handy @Jacob, if you could list what you have tried.

Have you tried the css display:inline?

Or have you tried putting them as `<li>`'s in a `<ul>` and then setting the display:inline on the ul or the li's?